# How do fix Error in angular code two binding

Tags: angular, xcode, binding, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

An error appear when using two binding
<input type="text" [(ngModel)] ="asd" >

TS2339: Property 'asd' does not exist on type 'Users Component'

Note :i add FormsModule in App. Module page.

So i don't know what the problem??

Comment: Have you declared "asd" in the class representing your component ? The error told you you have not or maybe there is a typo in it

Comment: Need the template and TS class code

Answer (score 0):

This error means that in your component "User Component" you don't have declared variable called "asd"

Just do

```
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

 asd: string;

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. In this case i see many videos to this technical and it's work without declare the variable